# Variable-like options in a package

Tags: package-writing, package-options

I turned my most used packages and macros and environments into a package (and defined options for some). There is one thing I could not figure out. Say I have this environment definition in my custom .sty file:

```
\newenvironment{myenvironment}
 {\par\addvspace{3ex}%
 \nopagebreak\noindent\hspace{0.5in}}
 {\par\addvspace{3ex}%
 \ignorespacesafterend}
```

Now, when I load the package, I'd like to have the ability to customize the options of this environment, such as (say):

```
\usepackage[myenvironment hspace=1in]{mydefaultpreamble}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: the standard option handler never takes values, however there are several extended versions eg the kvoptions package (based on the code developed for hyperref)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example with the `kvoptions` package.

```
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions {}

\ProvidesPackage{mydefaultpreamble} 
\DeclareStringOption[0.5in]{myenvironmenthspace}

\newenvironment{myenvironment}
 {\par\addvspace{3ex}%
 \nopagebreak\noindent\hspace{\mydefaultpreamble@myenvironmenthspace}}
 {\par\addvspace{3ex}%
 \ignorespacesafterend}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions{mydefaultpreamble}
```

And the use it

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[myenvironment hspace=5cm]{mydefaultpreamble}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenvironment}
  Some text
\end{myenvironment}

\setkeys{mydefaultpreamble}{myenvironmenthspace=2cm}

\begin{myenvironment}
  Another text
\end{myenvironment}

\end{document}
```

As you see, the key must be defined without spaces, but it can be used with spaces, although I would not recommend that. However in `\setkeys` it must be used without spaces.

Comment: is `\ProvidesPackage{mydefaultpreamble} ` needed every time I declare an option?

Comment: `\ProvidesPackage{mydefaultpreamble}` isn't strictly necessary. It is a nicety to tell what package it is, and it is only necessary once in the package. But it is good to do it, and you can also add a version number to it.